# Tengo un problema al insertar un datatable en un tabla de sql (Merge)

Tags: c#, sql

Mi problema es que yo quiero vaciar un datatable en una tabala temporal de sql, mi codigo ya llega al momento de ejecutar mi procedimiento almacenado que ejecutara la insercion del datatable.

Codigo de Insercion en c#

```
    try
    {
        comando = new SqlCommand("sp_Update_RectificacionesExportaciones", conexion);
        comando.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        comando.Parameters.AddWithValue("@tblRectificacionesExportaciones", dt_rectificacionesExportaciones);
        comando.CommandTimeout = 7200000;

        conexion.Open();
        comando.ExecuteReader();
        return "1";
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        return "0";
    }
```

Codigo del sp donde se hace el mergeo:

```
  MERGE INTO texportacion c1
  USING @tblRectificacionesExportaciones c2
  ON c1.idPedimento = c2.idPedimento
  and c1.idProducto = c2.idProducto
  and c1.factura = c2.factura
  and c1.secuencia= c2.secuencia
  and c1.descargado = 0
  WHEN MATCHED THEN
  UPDATE SET 
    c1.valorComercialUSD=c2.valorComercialUSD,
    c1.valorComercialMNX=c2.valorComercialMNX,
    c1.valorAduanaMNX=c2.valorAduanaMNX,
    c1.observación=c2.observación,
    c1.dta=c2.dta,
    c1.prv=c2.prv,
    c1.cove=c2.cove,
    c1.fechaFactura=c2.fechaFactura,
    c1.razonSocialCliente=c2.razonSocialCliente,
    c1.icoterm=c2.icoterm,
    c1.idMoneda=c2.idMoneda,
    c1.factorMonedaExtranjera=c2.factorMonedaExtranjera,
    c1.secuencia=c2.secuencia,
    c1.idFraccion=c2.idFraccion,
    c1.idPaisDestino=c2.idPaisDestino,
    c1.idPaisComprador=c2.idPaisComprador,
    c1.idUnidadComercial=c2.idUnidadComercial,
    c1.cantidad=c2.cantidad,
    c1.precioUnitario=c2.precioUnitario,
    c1.idTasa=c2.idTasa,
    c1.preferencia=c2.preferencia,
    c1.fechaActualizacion=c2.fechaActualizacion;
```

El error que me sale es el siguiente:

> The MERGE statement attempted to UPDATE or DELETE the same row more
>   than once. This happens when a target row matches more than one source
>   row. A MERGE statement cannot UPDATE/DELETE the same row of the target
>   table multiple times. Refine the ON clause to ensure a target row
>   matches at most one source row, or use the GROUP BY clause to group
>   the source rows.

Eh validado que cada campo concida con el de la tabla y que los tipos de valores sean similares. tambien eh checado que los campos obligatorios vayan llenos.

Esta es la informacion de mi datatable o @tblRectificaciones:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la estructura de mi tabal tExportacion es la siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Al momento de hacer mi insercion si la realiza, solo la actualizacion es la que no realiza.

Comment: Nos estás preguntando si tienes un problema? ;). De todas formas por favor postea también la estructura de la tabla `texportacion` y también `@tblRectificacionesExportaciones`

Comment: Otra pregunta, estás usando `MERGE` para sólo hacer un `UPDATE`?

Comment: @Lamak, si solo se usa para hacer el update o el insert eso depende de como se establezca en el codigo.

Comment: El problema es que el cruce que estás haciendo entre tablas entrega más de un resultado (es decir, hay algún duplicado). Esto deberías solucionarlo para que el cruce siempre entregue solo una fila. Por otro lado, si estás haciendo sólo un `UPDATE`, entonces deberías ocupar `UPDATE`, no `MERGE`. Es más, nunca deberías usar `MERGE`, tiene muchos bugs conocidos

Comment: @Lamak porque no usar merge, ¿es inconsistente?. solo curiosidad

Comment: En primer lugar, en tu caso no deberías usarlo porque sólo estás haciendo un `UPDATE`, para eso existe el comando `UPDATE`. Y en general, acá hay un link que explica diferentes problemas: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3074/use-caution-with-sql-servers-merge-statement/

Comment: El performance de merge no es el mejor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El error te aparece ya que al menos 2 filas en dt_rectificacionesExportaciones cumplen las mismas condiciones para un solo registro en la tabla texportacion.

Debes afinar las condiciones para el merge o verificar que la data que envias al store procedure no contenga registros duplicados.

En caso no estés enviando registros duplicados debes afinar esta condición:

```
ON c1.idPedimento = c2.idPedimento
and c1.idProducto = c2.idProducto
and c1.factura = c2.factura
and c1.secuencia= c2.secuencia
and c1.descargado = 0
```